# How to find value in a column based on min value from another column per group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this

[image]

I need to generate a new column which hold the **quota** of min **scale_qty** of each group created by **plant, material**. This is the expected result:

[image]

All that I can do so far is just to get the rows which contain the min **scale_qty** or find the minimum of **scale_qty** itself, I'm stucking at how the get the **quota** for each of that

`g = df.groupby(['plant', 'material']) df['min_scale_qty'] = g['scale_qty'].transform(min)`

I need your help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Please read here why you should never [provide data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), instead copy paste the data as text into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas.Series.idxmin) combined with `transform` to get the new column.

```
df['quota_of_min_scale_qty'] = (
    df.loc[
        df
        .groupby(['plant', 'material'])['scale_qty']
        .transform(lambda x: x.idxmin()), 'quota']
    .values
)
```

Comment: you saved me. This is very clean. Thank a lot!!!!

Need to bother you on one more thing, in case there are some min scale_qty that have the same value, then we want to get the min quota (right now the code is getting the first quota value that it found in the same min scale_qty). So are we able to achieve this?

Comment: i think we can sort the table first by plant, material and sap_quota to achieve this lol :D

Comment: so you are fine ? solved it yourself ? :D or should I have another look. Sorting sounds good to me

Comment: but I'm not sure whether it has good performance for big amount of data, so if you have some better approach than please let me know, I'd be very appreciate!